# Printing in Java

Tags: java, jsf, pdf

I just want to ask, We are creating a web-based system using JSF and Java. is there any way that I can Access the client's printer setting? or is it possible to configure programatically the printer settings of Acrobat Reader? because we created a Pdf file using IText and then print it by the client. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.

A webbrowser does not offer that functionality.